# Read entire file into memory?

Tags: bash

Is there any way to read entire file into memory in bash, without using external command like `cat`?

I know the syntax to get output from a file, i.e `<(/bin/ls)`, but now I need to read the file into entire memory, i.e `$A` would hold the contents (and there could be null, EOF like stuff)

Comment: Please note that "[no force in the universe can put NUL bytes into shell strings usefully](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Assigning_indirect.2BAC8-reference_variables)"

Comment: @l0b0 … unless the shell is zsh.

Comment: @Gilles Interesting; I hope that makes it to Bash someday (unless it would break too much). Maybe they should amend the text to "Bash strings."

Comment: @l0b0 Other shells (Bourne, ksh, ash, csh, tcsh) have the same restriction. They aren't designed to process binary data. Shell variables originated from environment variables which can't contain null bytes either. Unix favors text, and shells are geared towards handling text.

Comment: ksh can now store binary data using: typeset -b varname

Answer (score 7):

Bash doesn't support null bytes in variables. `foo=$(cat file)` makes `$foo` contain the beginning of the file, up to the first null byte. The command substitution also strips all final newlines from the file. For example, if the file consists of the four bytes (`a`, newline, newline, newline), then `foo` contains just `a`, same as if the file only contained that one byte.

If you want to preserve final newlines, arrange for the command to output an extra non-newline character, then strip it off.

```
foo=$(cat file; echo a)
foo=${foo%a}
```

So far this all worked in all Bourne/POSIX-style shells (ash, ksh, bash, …). Bash ≥4.0 has a faster way of reading a file into a variable: the [`mapfile`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-mapfile).

```
mapfile <file foo
```

There simply isn't a way to stuff a null byte into a bash variable. If you want this, you have several options:

- Use zsh.
- Use Perl.
- Store the data in a temporary file (which seems useless here, as the data is already in a file).
- Encode the input and decode it back, e.g. with `base64` and `base64 -d`.

Comment: why does https://gist.github.com/cirosantilli/9737428 fail with: `fail var: 61 0a GNU bash, version 4.2.25`?

Comment: @CiroSantilli `S` is an array. `"$S"` is the first element of the array in ksh and bash. It contains the first line: `a` and a newline. `${S[1]}` contains the second line: a newline. `${#S[@]}` is the array length which is 2.

Answer (score 6):

One way like this:

```
$ A=$(<file)
```

Instead of a variable, a better option would be to read into an array which makes it easier to access different lines:

```
$ OIFS=$IFS
$ IFS=$'\n'
$ arr=($(<file))
$ IFS=$OIFS
```

Comment: `echo $(</usr/bin/ls) > ls; diff ls /usr/bin/ls` differs, was it a problem with `echo`?

Comment: The `echo` command assumes that the input is 'printable' ASCII, not binary data.  The `ls` program file contains binary data.  Beyond that, the `echo` will likely append a trailing newline, which in itself makes it different from the actual contents.

Comment: Watch out: `arr=($(<file))` is an array of *words* in the file, not necessarily *lines* (assuming default value of $IFS). For an array of lines, use the `mapfile` command.

Comment: @glennjackman : Thanks glenn for  pointing it out..updated the solution using IFS since mapfile is available only from bash4...

Comment: @warl0ck: try it with `echo "$(</usr/bin/ls)" > ls`

Comment: @GertvandenBerg still differs

Comment: @warlOck: Should at least differ a lot less?